# Cloud storage consolidation application

Tags: windows, cloud-service

Is there any software to consolidate cloud services like Dropbox, Copy, Google Drive etc.?

I would like to get one desktop application (for Windows 7) to add files to all of them (and choose to which service I would like to add a certain file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All My Storage](http://allmystorage.org/)

**Description**

All My Storage (Free Edition) is a useful application that allows you to bring together your local storage, all your Box, Dropbox and multiple SkyDrive accounts into a simple, easy to use metro interface. All My Storage allows you to move your data around between local system, Box, SkyDrive and Dropbox.

Try out All My Storage Pro which includes SugarSync, Facebook, Google Drive, IDrive, Cloud Statistics, Extra Themes and Custom Themes.

**Features**

- File explorer for navigating local and cloud storage accounts
- Access the same accounts on your PC, Tablet or Laptop
- Easy search across local system Box, Dropbox and SkyDrive
- File and Hyperlink Sharing
- Copy between cloud storage accounts easily
- Change themes
- Speedy interaction with local caching
- File Open Location and File Save Target allowing easy transfer of items to and from your cloud storage accounts

---

[cloudfuze](https://www.cloudfuze.com/)

a desktop app that offers a single sign-on for your cloud-based services. Cloudfuze can connect Google Drive, Dropbox, Box, SugarSync and even FTP together. With these services in sync, you can edit, rename, create folders, drag and drop between your desktop and the Cloudfuze file manager, and share their contents. One handy feature is that Cloudfuze allows you to selectively sync files and folders across your cloud services. Cloudfuze is free and available for `Windows XP, 7, and Windows Server 2008`

is available for `android`,`iOS`

[download it for windows](http://download.cloudfuze.com/release/CloudFuze.msi)

[image]

---

[CarotDAV](http://rei.to/carotdav_en.html)

This is the only Windows desktop application I found that can help you manage multiple cloud storage services. The application is free for personal and commercial use but if you use it and find it useful you can donate to help with development. The website says it runs on Windows 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 2008, 7.
It supports:

FTP
SkyDrive
Dropbox
Google Drive
Box
SugarSync

[image]

---

See More @ [**10 Cloud Storage Managers**](https://cloudstoragebuzz.com/tips/cloud-storage-managers/) and [**Five tools to help sync more than one cloud storage service**](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-to-help-sync-more-than-one-cloud-storage-service/)

Comment: This app is only available for Win 8? I have win 7...

Comment: Yes, I really need a desktop app

Comment: It is great app, but, where you find information that it is free app?

Comment: Many thanks! I found that cloudfuze isn't free, unfortunately

Comment: CarotDAV is really cool. And developer is open to feedback.